# trim value in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to trim value in query .
$value variable is containing uploaded file name with blank spaces
I tried trimming value in code as well in in query

```
foreach ($_FILES[photo][name] as $key => $value) {
    // echo "ok";
    if($value!="")
    {

 $image_path= 'API/Uploads/';  
  $building_images_0  = $value;

  $building_images_0 = trim($building_images_0);

  //also tried 
   $target0 = $image_path . $building_images_0;

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key], $target0);

$query="update `tbl_site_attendace` 
SET `employees_location`='".$_POST['comment']."',`no_of_worker`='".$_POST['zip']."',`image_".++$key."`='".$value."' where `id`= '".$_POST['atendance_id']."'";
```

$update_query= $conn->query($query);

but this is not working . How can i modify the values so that it should not insert blank spaces

Comment: That code doesn't use any parameterized SQL query and is _wide open_ for SQL injections. Other than that, why not just trim it in PHP?

Comment: yes , i modified the topic

Comment: You should modified your code to actually use parameterized prepared statements instead. Then you can simply wrap the values in `trim($value)` when you bind the params.

Comment: Have you tried trimming it in PHP, instead ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: right cant change queries much , looking for simpler solution , i update php trim code also

Comment: This code is **_extremely_** insecure so I would argue that changing them would be priority one in all accounts. Please read: [SQL Injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: i will try modifying as per your suggestion , but right now i have urgent requirement for removing blankspaces

Comment: We already suggested how you can do it? Simply use `trim()` in PHP instead: `$value = trim($value);` before you use the variable.

Comment: i am saying about passing parameters

Comment: i updated the code , still not working

Comment: also tried    $building_images_0=preg_replace('/\s+/', '',$building_images_0); ......  not working

Answer (score 0):

OK , I did that with str_replace

```
 $new_value = str_replace(' ', '', $value);
 $building_images_0  = $new_value;
   $target0 = $image_path . $building_images_0;

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key], $target0);

    $query="update `tbl_site_attendace` 
    SET `employees_location`='".$_POST['comment']."',`no_of_worker`='".$_POST['zip']."',`image_".++$key."`='".$new_value."' where `id`= '".$_POST['atendance_id']."'";

   $update_query= $conn->query($query);
```